# How to print from mysql onto webpage?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm only a novice with SQL, so please help me.

I have a simple website with users who each have a username and password. I want to, on the Account page, print out the password like so `j******n` if the password is "Jonathan".

The problem is, I have the passwords encoded using the SQL function `ENCODE()`

I can use `DECODE()` to get the value in SQL, but then what? How do I ***print*** it out on the webpage (and then I'll format it)? I only know how to run queries using `mysqli_query()` and a `while` loop that *goes through* the queries.

Is there a function in SQL equivalent to PHP's `echo` that can print out a value on the webpage? Or does PHP have a function that can print out function from SQL?

Tell me if I'm unclear.

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Why use plain text passwords? Look into encryption.

Comment: link? use google, try to figure it out on your own first.

Comment: @DarylGill actually Jon should look into password hashing rather than encryption. Such as, bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution is to just use an alias.

```
> $query = "SELECT DECODE(foo,'key') AS somename FROM bar"; 
> $result =mysql_query($query); 
> echo mysql_result($result,'somename');
```

> or

```
> $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); echo $row['somename'];
```

> 

from: http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/php-mysql-encode-decode-57952.html

Answer (score 0):

Do not use MySQL's `ENCODE()` and `DECODE()` for passwords. Instead, use PHP's `password_hash()` to hash your password. You never want to store it in plaintext (or even encrypted), always hash.

While you still have it in plaintext (such as the point where you `password_hash()` it), store the hint version of it in a new coloumn of your database.

```
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$hint_password = substr($password, 0, 1) . str_repeat('*', strlen($password) -2) . substr($password, -1);
```

Now store `$hint_password` seperate from your `$hashed_password` in the database. This ensures:

- The password is never accessible in its original form
- You can still see the hint password